# LINQ Left join on condition having 'OR'

Tags: linq

I want to write this query in linq. Please help!!!

```
select  * from TableA a
join Table B b
on a.ID = b.ID
left join TableC c
on b.ID=c.ID or b.ID = c.Text
```

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 0):

> You dont need always a Join.

```
  var result =  from a in TableA
  from b in TableB
  from c in TableC
  where a.ID == b.ID && b.ID = c.ID || b.ID == c.Text
```